# Volley library has caused exception

Tags: android, android-volley

I have used volley to call api's so the version I was using is "**compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'**" but today almost after 5 months it seems some error has caused after I imported my project work in another laptop so I am getting error after running

> W/System.err: remove failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) :
>   /data/user/0/in.medma.callbin/files/.Fabric/com.crashlytics.sdk.android.crashlytics-core/log-files/crashlytics-userlog-59DC9B9B0184-0001-3355-3FD34D64056C.temp
>
> E/UncaughtException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke
>   virtual method 'int java.lang.String.hashCode()' on a null object
>   reference
>                            at com.android.volley.Request.(Request.java:136)
>                            at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.(StringRequest.java:43)
>                            at in.medma.callbin.LoginActivity$5.(LoginActivity.java:0)
>                            at in.medma.callbin.LoginActivity.requestForSMS(LoginActivity.java:203)
>                            at in.medma.callbin.LoginActivity.validateForm(LoginActivity.java:189)
>                            at in.medma.callbin.LoginActivity.onClick(LoginActivity.java:155)

In Fabric crashlytic I am getting this

[image: CrashReport]

Volley request

```
private void requestForSMS(final String mobile) {
        StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                Config.URL_REQUEST_SMS, new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

                try {
                    JSONObject responseObj = new JSONObject(response);

                    // Parsing json object response
                    // response will be a json object
                    boolean error = responseObj.getBoolean("error");
                    String message = responseObj.getString("message");

                    // checking for error, if not error SMS is initiated
                    // device should receive it shortly
                    if (!error) {
                        // boolean flag saying device is waiting for sms
                        pref.setIsWaitingForSms(true);
                        viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Error: " + message,
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                    // hiding the progress bar


                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Error: " + e.getMessage(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }) {

            /**
             * Passing user parameters to our server
             * @return
             */
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("mobile", mobile);
                Log.e(TAG, "Posting params: " + params.toString());

                return params;
            }

        };

        // Adding request to request queue
        MyApplication.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq);
    }
```

Comment: `compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0` deprecated

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya Thanks which one I can use please give the link

Comment: `compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'`

Comment: use this one  
    compile 'eu.the4thfloor.volley:com.android.volley:2015.05.28'

Comment: @SushinPv above is not official AFAIK

Comment: Check the URL once again

Comment: @SushinPv Do i need to put http before my server address?

Comment: @MohammadSameerKhan Yes u have to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compile with

> compile 'eu.the4thfloor.volley:com.android.volley:2015.05.28'

Comment: compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19' ?? this is one working can you please verify

Comment: NetworkDispatcher.run: Unhandled exception java.lang.RuntimeException: Bad URL I got this when Used  
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19' malformed it says when I searched on google

Comment: Check Your URL. Its not hitting the server. That's the error @MohammadSameerKhan

Comment: check I have added code above and also api to check if its working or not use postman

Answer (score 0):

**DEPRECATED
Please note, this project is deprecated and no longer being maintained, please use official version volley.**

compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'

Comment: Yes. Try to replace your library by google volley. and the problem should be solved.

Comment: NetworkDispatcher.run: Unhandled exception java.lang.RuntimeException: Bad URL I got this when Used compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19' malformed it says when I searched on google